# How's a function that returns it's first argument useful?

Tags: java, function, jvm, arguments, parameter-passing

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/4ef4b1ed7a2e8bb0aaaacfb0942729252c2c3091/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Util.java#L197) function. This function takes two arguments and returns the first argument it was passed. How could such a function be useful?

Comment: Why ask us? Ask the author.

Comment: @Turing85 I thought it might have something to do with `jvm` or `compiler` internals, and wanted to know more if that's the case.

Comment: Maybe if the methodes are called dynamically, why not. But to be honest, this inded seems convoluted :/.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of one scenario:

Suppose you have a Stream of some objects and you collect them into a `Map`. Some of the `Collectors.toMap()` variants have a merge function parameter that handles merging duplicate keys. I.e. if the same key has multiple values, the merge function determines which value will be associated with that key.

```
public static <T, K, U>
Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                                BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

As you can see, the merge function is a `BinaryOperator<U>` - a function that takes two arguments of the same type and returns a result of that same type.

If you want a merge function that always uses the first value that was associated with a given key, and ignores any following values, you'll need **a function that receives two arguments and returns the first one**. Of course, such a function can be easily written using a simply lambda expression - `(v1,v2)->v1`, so you don't have to define an explicit method that does that.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, one needs to merge 2 or more values into one. If "merging" doesn't really mean anything other than selecting one of the values, then such a function may be needed.

Take a look at this fabricated example:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, 20)
                .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf( i % 3))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Function.identity(), 
                            String::length, 
                            (a, b) -> a)
                        );
```

According to `Collectors.toMap`, `mergeFunction` is "used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key, as supplied to Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)". So in this hypothetical requirement, the result `{0=1, 1=1, 2=1}` is fine (find any integer for each result of remainder divisions by 3).

In the logic of the above integer stream, I just need to find any element by key, so a function that selects just one element is fine.